# Submitting a form and refreshing a fields_for partial via Ajax - undefined local variable f in response

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, nested-forms

There are many resources dealing with Rails forms and simple ajax crud interfaces like those famous Post -> comment examples. However, my problem is a little more complex and I can't seem to get it working.

I have a form for orders, which can consist of several line_items. Those line_items are added and removed before submitting anything with the help of the nested_form gem by ryan bates. That's all fine and it works flawlessly.

Now I want to add some dynamic behavior. When some of the line_item input fields are changed totals and other calculations should be updated. When selecting another product for that line_item its price should be updated and displayed before submitting the form. Stuff like that. My first approach was doing those calculations in JavaScript, which while working, soon made me realize that I'm doubling all the logic I defined in the models of my app anyway. Plus, it's a mess doing this in JS since you don't have access to the instance variables.

After some thought I wanted submit and refresh those fields_for line_item partials as soon as someone changed certain input values. This should be the basic workflow:

User input -> submit order (or just line_item if possible) -> return updated line_item partial with refreshed calculations, etc.

In the future I'd like to extend this behaviour to a point where I won't need a save button any longer.

However I don't want to re-render the whole form (too slow for fast user input), just the current fields_for partial.

The problem is that whenever I limit my js response to re-rendering the current fields_for partial, the needed f variable from `form_for @order do |f|` is missing. If I replace the whole form in my response, it's working fine.

Here's the current code:

**/views/orders/_form.html.slim**

```
= nested_form_for @order do |f|
  ...
  #line-items
    = f.fields_for :line_items do |line_item|
      = render "orders/line_item_fields", f: line_item
  ...
```

**views/orders/_line_item_fields.html.slim**

```
...

= f.label :product_id, "Product"
= f.collection_select(:product_id, Product.order(:name), :id, :name, class: "order_line_items_product_id submittable" )

= f.label :quantity
= f.text_field :quantity, class: "submittable"

= f.label :price
= f.text_field :price, class: "submittable"

...

.totals
  p
    span = f.object.total_price
```

**/app/assets/javascripts/orders.js.erb**

```
$('body').on('change', '.submittable', function () {
  var current_item = $(this).closest('section')
  var order_id = $('form.edit_order').data('order-id')
  var data = $('form.edit_order').serialize();

  current_item.addClass('item-to-refresh')

  $.ajax({
    url: "/orders/" + order_id,
    data: data,
    dataType: "script",
    type: "patch",
    error: function(response) {
      response
    },
    success: function(response){
      response
    }
  });
}
```

**/app/controllers/orders_controller.rb**

```
...

def update
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  authorize @order

  if @order.update_attributes(order_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        redirect_to order_path
        flash[:success] = "Order #{@order.id} saved"
      end
      format.js
    end
  else
    render 'edit'
  end

end

...
```

**/app/views/orders/update.js.erb**

```
$('.item-to-refresh').replaceWith("<%= j render 'orders/line_item_fields' %>")
```

As mentioned above the response always comes with the error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method 'f' for #class...` - I understand it needs the f variable, but how do I pass it? I tried adding `f: f`, `f: line_item` and similar variations on the theme to the render function from  **update.js.erb** to no success. Naturally, the whole process works flawlessly if I don't try to render form elements in the response but a simple `<p>It works!</p>`

Also, is the general concept I had in mind here a good way to handle interactivity in web apps? This is still an old-school documents/page based app where reloading pages is just fine. But for certain parts of the app users just expect to get instant feedback and results - hitting "Save" to get some calculations and totals isn't enough these days.
On the other hand (and unless the code above doesn't tell you already) I hate Javascript and like to keep it to a minimum while solving these problems. So, I'd like to find a reusable way to submit and refresh partials on change events.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
= render "orders/line_item_fields", :locals => {f: line_item}
```

or

```
= render partial: "orders/line_item_fields", :locals => {f: line_item}
```

Comment: Same result, I already tried `render "orders/line_item_fields", f: line_item` which is a shorthand for your code, isn't it? Should those variables maybe be used in the controller action? Because I'm not sure where they would come from otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I had the same Problem that I want to rerender the fields_for form after update the record without rendering the complete form.

My solution is to change the id and name attributes of every input(select, checkbox, etc) field which was dynamically created by javascript with the correct id and name after updating(and creating the record in the database). At the end the dynamically field looks like a field which was created by the form builder for an edit-field.

Additional to changing the id and name attributes it needs an extra input type=hidden field after the fields_for form element. This also needs the correct id and name syntax like the fields in the form and the value attribute must be the new record id.

Hopefully this helps!